# How to store/update a list of Hive Object(HiveList) to a Hive Object

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I want to store List of Hive Object `Model2` to a Hive Object `Model1`

Here is my data Model:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Model1 extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int? id;
  @HiveField(1)
  HiveList<Model2>? list;

  Model1({this.id, this.list});
}

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Model2 extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int? id;
  @HiveField(1)
  String? name;

  Model2({this.id, this.name});
}
```

At first I stored the `Model1` with this:

```
await model1Box.add(Model1(id: counter, list: HiveList<Model2>(model2Box)));
```

And then I tried this way to store/update this list of `Model2` to `Model1` :

```
    var _object = Model2(id: counter, name: 'Name $counter');

    await model2Box.add(_object);

    model1Box.values.last.list!.add(_object);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: use List instead of HiveList

Comment: No. It is not working too. If I use List, then it just updates the list temporarily.  But, when I restart the list is gone.

Comment: you mean hot restart or full restart?

Comment: I mean full restart.

Comment: Of course, full restart resets data to last full restart, so your data is lost. Hot restart save files temporarily